# UITextField: adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth behaviour/ issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have an issue with the usage of textField’s `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`. I have a textField with font size of 50 and a maximum width of 300 (This is a less than or equal to constraint). TextField is placed centre vertically and horizontally using auto layout. Now when I run the app, the text is being shrinked from the beginning itself. I know this may be because the system thinks the bounds of Texfield is not enough… but I gave the control to auto layout to figure that out and I assume it should work. Below is the snapshot… you can see the big `placeholder` and then suddenly the text shrinks… Any thoughts? Am I doing something wrong, I was trying to avoid manual calculation of width..

[SourceCode Sample](https://github.com/anoop4real/TextFieldTest)

[image]

Comment: I would expect you want to set the width to 300 ... not `<=`, and set the text alignment to center.

Comment: @DonMag I have updated the question to be more clear , I cant set fixed width because I have another control to the right... I haved added link to source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay!! Finally I found a way, the idea was to check if the width is greater than the defined width limit... when the width is more I set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` else set to `false` ... for some reason the solution didnt work when I clear the text... then I tried programatical approach and it started working .... dont know what was the difference... anyways I updated the source..... if there is a better solution let me know.

```
    @IBAction func textChanged(_ txtField: UITextField) {
    if txtField.frame.width >= (view.frame.width * widthMultiplier).rounded() {
        txtField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    } else {
        txtField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set leading/trailing space to text field like 15 pt from left safe area and 15 from Button so that it could automatically increase the font size. As now it shrinks the font to minimal 17 (which is set in storyboard) as the width is not enough.

[image]

Comment: Its already added.... I have updated the question with source...

Comment: Look at my answer above, I've tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: This solution wont work as i want the button also to move along

Comment: I’m happy that you’ve found a workable solution in the end